# Python - Run a program using multiple different files

Tags: python

My research group requires me to run a bunch of different test cases for several different problems.  All in all, there are 486 different files with 81 for each problem.  I know very little about Python and all I've managed to do so far is get it to run one test file.  The command to run the problem solver from the command line is this:

```
python Solver.py Tests/testName.txt
```

Of course, I don't plan on typing out the name of each file over and over because that takes far too long.  Is there any way for me to run this command for every file in that Tests folder?  The files are all named using the same format, where it's something like [original_filename]_[Precision][Criteria][SpeculationLevel][PreconditionLevel].txt, where precision, criteria, speculationLevel, and preconditionLevel each have three possible values.  I originally wrote the files using nested for loops but that was in Java.

Comment: You could incorporate the file handling into the code itself, or write a script that runs the python file for each test file.

Comment: `python Solver.py Test/*.txt`

Comment: I got an error from running that line.  The last line of it reads, "IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+') or filename: 'Tests/*.txt.tmp'

Comment: Are you on Windows? That may be why `python Solver.py Test/*.txt` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a script that runs it for you.

```
import glob
import subprocess as sub

for file in glob.glob("Tests/*.txt"): # or however you want to build the list
    sub.call(["python","Solver.py",file])
```

Comment: So *.type specifies all files of some type in a directory?

Comment: @user3308219 `*` is usually used as a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) character. `glob.glob("Tests/*.txt")` will give you a list with all the files in it that match that file path.

Comment: @user3308219 for example, `"cat*"` would match `cat`,`catatonic`,`category`, `catherine`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adsmith's answer with glob.glob should've worked for you (on Windows, too), but here is another thing to try.  It'd be run by passing a folder name as the argument: `python runner.py Tests`

```
import fnmatch, os, subprocess, sys
folder = sys.argv[1]
for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(folder), '*.txt'):
    subprocess.call(['python', 'Solver.py', filename])
```